# Request failed with status code 504 from nginx

Tags: java, reactjs, docker, nginx, openshift

I'm still learning, so I apologize if I'm wrong.
I am working on a project with React as the frontend and Java + Spring as the backend.
The project is being tested and we are using Nginx as a reverse proxy.

I am experiencing this problem in an http call with axios.

In practice I make a call that goes to take about 60k data from the database and generates an excel (via Workbook) by entering all the data inside.
This takes about 35 seconds. My problem is that at 30s I get out: **request failed with status code 504**, but the backend is continuing to run.

I added the timeout to the Axios call, it works, but that's not the problem.

Reading on the internet, the problem seems to be the nginx timeout. Reading various guides, I read to add:

```
proxy_connect_timeout 900;
proxy_send_timeout 900;
proxy_read_timeout 900;
send_timeout 900;
```

To the nginx.conf file.
Since I don't have this path locally.
But I found it through OpenShift terminal, is there a way to add these lines to that file? Should I add them via terminal? Or is there some simpler way?

I tried adding these lines to my project config file, but it doesn't work.
Thanks to anyone who helps me and I apologize if I may have been unclear about some things or if I was wrong to write something.

Comment: Could you add more information on what container image you are using and if you are already using a `ConfigMap` for your Pod?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I'm using Docker as a container and I'm using ConfigMap where I added the 4 lines above.

Comment: You should check out https://github.com/redhat-cop/container-pipelines/tree/master/basic-nginx